# When are the curves $a =xy$ and $b = (1-x)(1-y)$ tangential?

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry

I've seen that the curves $xy = 1/4$ and $(1-x)(1-y) =1/4$ are tangential at the point $(x,y) = (1/2,1/2).$

Similarly I can see that the curves $xy = 1/16$ and $(1-x)(1-y) = 9/16$ are tangential at $(x,y) = (1/4,1/4).$

I therefore have the general conjecture that $a = xy$ and $b = (1-x)(1-y)$ are tangential when $a=z^2$ and $b = (1-z)^2,$ for some $z \in (0,1),$ with the tangential being $(x,y)=(z,z).$

However I try to prove this by solving the system of equations $y = \frac{a}{x}$ and $y=1-\frac{b}{1-x},$ but I am stuck in getting to an expression in terms of a parameter $z,$ as above.

Answer (score 1):

Your conjecture works if there is a specific relationship between values of $a$ and $b$.

First curve is $y = \frac{a}{x}$
Second curve is $y = 1 - \frac{b}{1-x}$

For your general conjecture to be true we should have only one point where both curves meet,

So, $\frac{a}{x} = 1 - \frac{b}{1-x}$ should have exactly one solution for $x$ if they both meet and also they do not intersect.

$x^2 + (b-a-1)x + a = 0$ will have only one solution if its discriminant is zero.

i.e $(b-a-1)^2 = 4a \implies b = a + 1 \pm 2 \sqrt a$ ...(i)
(you have to specifically check whether $+$ works or $-$ works).

This relationship between $a$ and $b$ also means $x = y$ at the point of tangent.

I used your working which assumes $x = y = z$.

So, $z^2 = a \implies z = \pm \sqrt a, (1 - z)^2 = b \implies b = a + 1 \pm 2\sqrt a \,$ which is same as (i).

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much! I forgot that the discriminant would equal zero at the tangential point, so couldn't get b in terms of a without x.

Comment: @user130075 you are welcome.